# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/objects/XObject

Tags: java, migration, java-7, java-6

I am trying to migrate my application from JRE6 to JRE7 on LINUX machine. I am getting this error `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/xpath/objects/XObject` while I was deploying the application.

One of the `jar`(which would be compiled with some lower JAVA version) calls some function in the class XObject.

Is there any possibility to have version compatibility issue. I have not changed anything in build.xml file and it perfectly runs fine on JRE6.

Answer (score 1):

You have do add the `xalan.jar` to your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

```
org/apache/xpath/objects/XObject
```

above error indicate that there is no such type of class found in your project right?

So you have to need the above jar file of `org/apache/xpath/objects/XObject` and complie your java class with following command as class path reference. You can download this jar from here http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/x/Downloadxalan240jar.htm

```
javac -cp jar_file_path.jar pachakge/java_file.java
```